# Java Timer stops for no reason

Tags: java, linux, timer, raspberry-pi, schedule

I'm new to Java so sorry if the problem is trivial. My code is probably a mess. I created a online radio player for Raspberry Pi in Java and I have to do a POST request every 10 seconds to check what is the current song playing and if the song has changed, I have to do some things (like scrobble old song, update display with new song data, store play session to my server etc.). I created a class for this:

```
public class Scrobbler implements Runnable, Commands, Observer {
    private TimeCounter counter;
    private Timer timer;
    private Radio radio;
    private List<Observer> observers;
    private final Object MUTEX= new Object();
    private int currentPlaySession;
    // And all other variables which I deleted before posting

    // Constructor
    public Scrobbler(TimeCounter _counter, Radio _radio)
    {
        currentTrack = null;
        counter = _counter;
        radio = _radio;
        timer = null;
        observers = new ArrayList<>();
        currentPlaySession = 0;
    }

    private void GetInfo()
    {
        // POST request to get current song playing
        // If song has changed, notify observers
    }

    public void Scrobble()
    {
        // POST request - Scrobble song to my website and last.fm
    }

    public void StartPlaySession()
    {
        // Again POST request to my website
    }

    public void EndPlaySession()
    {
        // Again POST request to my website
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void register(Observer obj) {
        if(obj == null) throw new NullPointerException("Null Observer");
        synchronized (MUTEX) {
            if(!observers.contains(obj)) observers.add(obj);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void unregister(Observer obj) {
        synchronized (MUTEX) {
            observers.remove(obj);
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObservers(String command) {
        for (Observer obj : observers) {
            obj.update(command);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimeOut(), 0, 10000);
        GetInfo();
        StartPlaySession();
    }

    public class TimeOut extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            EndPlaySession();
            GetInfo();
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void update(String command) {
        if ("RADIO_STARTED".equals(command))
        {
            this.start();
        }

        if ("RADIO_STOPPED".equals(command))
        {
            this.stop();
            if (this.currentTrack != null && this.counter.getTrackTime() >= 60)
                this.Scrobble();
            EndPlaySession();
        }
    }

    private void handleException(String message)
    {
        try {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/pi/OnlineRadio/error_log.txt", true)));
            out.println("(" + timeStamp + ") [SCROBBLER] - " + message + "\n\n\r");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        this.stop();
        this.start();
    }
}
```

I create a new instance of Scrobbler in my main method and register it as an observable to player. Once I start the radio, player will notify its observers (including instance of Scrobbler class) by calling update() method and forward "RADIO_STARTED" or "RADIO_STOPPED" (after starting or stopping the radio). As you can see in code, on RADIO_STARTED, a start() method is called where new Thread is started. Starting a new thread is probably unnecessary here since it only starts the timer but it shouldn't be a problem neither. After starting the timer, every 10 seconds method run() in class TimeOut will be called which then calls necessary methods.

This code works but sometimes it just stops for no reason. All other parts of application continue to work (music is still playing, application reacts on buttons etc.), just it doesn't update the song and there's no communication with my website at all so not even one of these methods is called, just like the timer stopped. When I stop and start the radio again or change the station, it works again (as you can see in code, the timer will be stoped every time the radio stops and the timer will start everytime the radio starts), but it will break again after some time.

Since I have a lot of try-catch blocks in those methods with POST requests, at first I thought that there must be an exception occuring and killing the timer thread so I created the handleException() method which logs exception message to a file and restarts this timer (you can see in code), and then I handle exceptions like this, for example:

```
try {
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    this.handleException(e.getMessage());
}
```

But when the problem occured again, log file was empty, which means that not even one exception occured. I also tried to log all the data everytime the song changes and everything is fine, it just stops after a while for no reason. And I can't find a regularity in occuring, sometimes it occurs after a few minutes and sometimes if works for hours before it breaks.

This app runs on Raspberry Pi model B, and I don't know if this means something, but it's in JAR and it starts with the Pi (via cron @reboot) since I don't have any monitor nor keyboard/mouse on this Pi, so the app must start with it and run in background all the time. And I use SSH to transfer the JAR to Pi and to read log files.

Somewhere I read that it's not uncommon for the Java timer to stop without any reason. But how to solve this?

Comment: Why are you using a timer and spawning a thread?

Comment: I spawned a thread because I thought that it will be active as long as timer is running (which would freeze my main thread) but I was wrong and noticed that the thread just starts timer to late, but is this a problem? I can remove the thread if neccessary.

And for timer, why not? Is there a better solution for calling a method every 10 seconds?

Comment: Could it be a deadlock? Or the server not responding and the client waiting forever?

Comment: Maybe, I didn't even think that something like this could happen, I thought that it will throw an exception if the server don't respond. Furthermore, I'm having problems with my internet connection these days so it's highly possible but how to eliminate this problem? I'm thinking about something like a watchdog, which will expect from Scrobble instance to notify it every 10 seconds, othervise it will restart the timer. But it's not an elegant solution. Or maybe running POST requests in new thread to avoid deadlocks on timer? Also, is timer.scheduleAtFixedRate a better solution maybe?

Comment: PS: once when it occured, it passed 20 minutes from the moment it stopped to the moment I noticed. I don't think that server wasn't able to respond in these 20 minutes. Internet connection didn't crash because the music was playing all the time (and the music is an online radio streamed from the internet as well).

Comment: Now I'm reading that it's not possible to stop a timer task. What to do if server is not responding and timer task waits for it forever? I cerated a watchdog class which expects from the Scrobbler to notify it every 10 seconds, otherwise it will stop and start the timer, but what will happen with that task which is blocked waiting forever?